# I would like to output list from a gridview output

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a table that contains all employee data, it is a flat sql table. It contains General managers who manage managers, and managers who manage team leaders, who manage agents. I have an output on gridview which lists all agents under the GM, that is fine but what I need to do is limit the managers to view only the agents that are under his group. His group is usually composed of 5 team leaders who manage around 8 agents each.
I currently can output the the team leaders from their group on a gridview, the field I need is called Full_name. What I can't do is create a loop that can loop on the gridview full_name column as that name is the supervisor_name on the agents record and it's that field that will pull the agents under the team leaders under the managers.
I am using linq to create the query that fills the gridview.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
Protected Sub allbymgr_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles allbymgr.Click 

Dim dC As New APDDataClassesDataContext()
    Dim MG = From p In dC.ALLs_employees _ 
    Where p.SUPERVISOR_NAME = lblfname.Text And _
     p.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS = "A" _ 
     Order By p.FULL_NAME _ 
      Select p.FULL_NAME, p.LOCATION_NAME, p.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS, _ 
       p.SUPERVISOR_NAME 
      GridView3.DataSource = MG 
      GridView3.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it sounds like you are using one mega query to pull the main data and then storing that in a gridview and then querying the gridview columns to create more data.

If this is true a better approach would be to have separate queries for each set of data rather than trying to retrieve it out oa gridview once its been databound and lost some of its meaning